# how would I create this list?

Tags: python, list, integer

A function that creates a list of 'a' random integers in the range of 'a' to (a+b) and then prints that list inside the function. The function returns a list of integers, taken from the list it initially created, that are multiple of b. print out the list that the function returns.

this is what I came up with, but its not what my professor is looking for.

```
import random

def randomNumberList(a, b):
    result = []

    for i in range(a, a + b*2):
        temp = random.randint(a, b*2)
        result.append(temp) 
   
    return result

a = int(input("Enter a positive Integer: "))
b = int(input("Enter a positive Integer: "))

print(randomNumberList(a, b))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "this is what I came up with, but its not what my professor is looking for." Well, **what happens** when you try using that code? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen? Please read [ask] and identify a **specific problem**, and then **ask a question** about it.

Answer (score -1):

```
from random import randint

def RandInts( a, b ):
    c = [ randint( a, a + b ) for idx in range( 0, amount_nums_you_want_to_create ) ]
    print( c )
    d = [ num for num in c if num % b == 0 ]
    return d
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer] and only attempt to answer questions that are actually asked. A requirement specification and a code dump does not make a question - we can't tell whether OP is trying to figure out a specific technique, or looking for help with debugging, or just what. Simply dumping code to meet a specification also doesn't answer a question - code should be explained.